Can I safely catch and ignore BadHttpRequestException: Unexpected end of request content. in ASP.NET Core
We have a website with a lot of traffic. Especially during peak hours when people browse a lot of pages rapidly we are getting Exceptions in our log that look like this:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Unexpected end of request content.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1ContentLengthMessageBody.ReadAsyncInternal(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpRequestStream.ReadAsyncInternal(Memory`1 destination, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBufferAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadAsyncInternal(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadDataAsync(Boolean append, Int32 charsRequired, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValueAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   [...]

I don't want to focus on the code itself, because it is irrelevant.
It's something similar to this during ValueProviding for ASP.NET:
var stream_reader = new StreamReader(context.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Body);

var json_reader = new JsonTextReader(stream_reader);

bool success = await json_reader.ReadAsync();

I have never been able to replicate these errors in my debug environment. I have the feeling they happen when an XHR request is happening while a user changes the page.
That some browsers just stop the whole request, so they don't send the payload anymore that they promised.
These are just assumptions though. It's really hard for me to find any information about it.
I found this thread, but it's a lot of scattered opinions.
Some people are waiting for a bugfix from ASP.NET, but in the mean time this is completely littering my logs with errors.
Question: Can I safely just catch BadHttpRequestException exceptions here and ignore them? Or might I be missing out on critical errors? Is there any decisive information on this?
Please note that I am aware how to catch the exception.
I'm looking for information:

if I should
understanding when this happens.


It would be great if you could share the exact code from where the exception has been thrown. Additionally, you can safely catch and ignore BadHttpRequestException for example, when users navigate away mid-request, Implement global exception handling middleware to catch and log these exceptions as warnings, reducing log noise. Also, adjust your logging configuration to filter out these exceptions, ensuring critical errors remain visible. This keeps your logs clean and focused on significant issues.

Hi @MdFaridUddinKiron, I added the code

Do you know what are you getting at context.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Body? Is there any way to get the demo data same as your request body so that it can be investigate accordingly.


Can I safely just catch BadHttpRequestException exceptions here and
ignore them? Or might I be missing out on critical errors? Is there
any decisive information on this?

Based on your shared code snippet and description I have tried to reproduced your issue. However, as you also mentioned that it occurred intermittently its hard to reproduce the issue at my end as well.
Because, this might be messed up due to lot of reasons. For instance missing request body parts, wrong format, or too big, it throws a BadHttpRequestException. This usually happens because of a network issue, user cancellation, wrong content type, missing headers, or an incorrect request method.
So in order to fix the issue, its hard to offer you any direct solution, instead, you could continue log the error when it usually took place, try to check the application log, event viewer log.
If this exception certainly blocking your application, you could catch the error and and log and finally ignore or throw the response, so that it wouldn't restirct the method execution.
You could do as following:
public class BadReqeustHandlerController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<BadReqeustHandlerController> _logger;

    public BadReqeustHandlerController(ILogger<BadReqeustHandlerController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("BadRequestBodyHandlerMethod")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> BadRequestBodyHandlerMethod()
    {
        try
        {
           
            string requestBody;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body))
            {
                requestBody = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }

            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(requestBody);
            return Ok(data);
        }
        catch (BadHttpRequestException ex) when (ex.Message.Contains("Unexpected end of request content"))
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("BadHttpRequestException: Unexpected end of request content - {Message}", ex.Message);

            // Ignore this exception, as it's likely due to client disconnection
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, "Client disconnected before the request could be completed.");
        }
        catch (JsonException ex)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("JSON exception occurred: {Message}", ex.Message);
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, "Malformed JSON request.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "An unexpected error occurred");
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "An unexpected error occurred.");
        }
    }
}

Note: As you can see, when there would be no error or exception the method would execute without any issue. But while there's would any issue either BadHttpRequestException or JsonException immediately it would log the error and return the response without blocking the operation.
Output:

Note: Please keep in mind this not the exact solution as I told you earlier. Apart from above exception handler within catch, you could also consider asp.net core middleware to handle any kind of intermittent issue. In addition, you could refer this official document for few more mechanism to manage this kind error or exception.

Hi Md Farid, thanks a lot for your extended answer. I think it will help other people, but for me it's not a problem how I can solve it. I want to know what actually triggers this and if I safely can safely ignore it, because i.e. they are "abandoned requests" on the client side, or "bad connection" on the client side - so there is nothing I should / could do.

Yeah that' correct, as I told you earlier its hard to offer any direct solution for that, instead we could investigate or return the exception in response, because its a intermittent issue and hardly reproduce.
